# How do I install mongodb in Google Colab with the new Ubuntu 22.04 update?

Tags: database, mongodb, ubuntu-22.04

I want to access my mongodb server within Google Colab.
For this, I have to install and run mongodb within Google Colab.

With the new Ubuntu 22.04 update I am unable to get this to work.

Has anybody found a good work around?

I tried many installations and none have been working. What has worked for other people?
!sudo service mongodb start
Always results in mongodb: unrecognized service

Comment: Try webapps.stackexchange.com or perhaps stack overflow (but read the rules first to see if this question is ontopic there)

Comment: It was originally on stack overflow and was migrated here